# How to change placeholder colour on input focus?

Tags: css, hover

I want to if user clicks on input, I mean `input:focus`, the placeholder colour become blue, for example, how do I do it?
This is not working

```html
   <input id="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
```

```css
input:focus ~ ::placeholder{
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need the `~` for this to work

```css
input:focus::placeholder{
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="ding">
```